# Problem with memory when I try to deploy my xgboost models on heroku

Tags: django, heroku, xgboost

I have deployed five xgboost models on heroku using django. After success deployment I have received the next message:

> Warning: Your slug size (321 MB) exceeds our soft limit (300 MB) which may affect boot time.

But the max available size is 500 MB. And as a result my app doesn't work correctly. For example my css styles can't be upload and when I try to go to an other page of my app it crashes with message:
[image]

So how can I solve this problem?
For your information the biggest object is xgboost liblary.

Comment: Can I win some memory if I use my own git repo instead of heroku git or not?